# Assembly translation

Tags: assembly, x86, 32-bit, intel-syntax

I am trying to translate the following C code to assembly:

```
void write (int bitpos, unsigned short sample)
{
    int pos = bitpos / 16;
    int posA = bitpos - pos * 16;
    unsigned short write1 = sample >> posA;
}
```

I keep getting an error in the shift operation. I looked at some examples in a book but I don't understand what's wrong. I think it may be because the quantity that I want to shift is a variable. I was wondering what the correct way to achieve this is?

Here is what I have tried:

```
//int pos = bitpos / 16;
mov eax, 0
mov eax, [bitpos] // eax= bitpos
cdq
mov ecx, 16         
idiv ecx        //ecx = pos

//int posA = bitpos - pos * 16;
mov ebx, ecx    //ebx = pos
imul ebx, 16    // ebx = pos*16
sub eax, ebx    // eax = posA

//unsigned short write1 = sample >> posA;
mov bx, [sample]
shr bx, eax // This is the part that is not working.
```

The error says: Wrong operand type. Error code: C2415

Comment: Try using `sar` instead of `shr`. This preserves sign.

Comment: A good assembler reference should state that the only register to indicate a variable shift is [in CL](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_285.html).

Comment: You can replace `bitpos / 16` with `bitpos >> 4` and `pos * 16` with `pos << 4`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `write()` function has no return value and no side effects (no writes to any global variable, no system calls, only setting some locals which are discarded when the function returns).  You can and should optimize it away to an empty function, [just like gcc does](http://goo.gl/8LW3Hb).

```
global write
write:
    ret
```

---

Let's pretend your function returns the `write1` variable, so you do have to calculate it.

`gcc -Og` (optimize for debugging) makes nice readable asm that doesn't store/reload from memory all the time.  [`gcc -m32 -Og -fverbose-asm -masm=intel` emits](http://goo.gl/dePuju):

```
# see the godbolt link for colour-coded mapping of source lines to asm lines
write(int, unsigned short):
    mov edx, DWORD PTR [esp+4]  # bitpos, bitpos
    lea eax, [edx+15]   # tmp98,
    test    edx, edx    # bitpos
    cmovns  eax, edx    # tmp98,, bitpos, bitpos
    sar eax, 4  # tmp99,
    neg eax # tmp101
    sal eax, 4  # tmp102,
    mov ecx, eax    # tmp102, tmp102
    add ecx, edx    # posA, bitpos
    movzx   eax, WORD PTR [esp+8]   # D.2591, sample
    sar eax, cl # D.2591, posA
    ret
```

Note how it loads function parameters from the stack, because they're function parameters, not globals.  (Your code references `[bitpos]`, a global, not the first position on the stack after the return address, `[esp+4]`.)  The 64bit ABI passes args in registers, so you get cleaner code.

The conditional-move code is there because the C semantics for integer division of a negative number give different results from arithmetic right-shift (they round differently).  Since `idiv` is very expensive compared to a shift, it's still worth using extra instructions to set up for a shift.  If `bitpos` was unsigned, it could just use `shr`.

With full optimization on, gcc finds a more efficient way to do things, and folds some of the arithmetic together.  (i.e. the divide by 16 and then multiply by 16, to round to the nearest multiple of 16, is implemented with a single `and` to mask off those bits.)

Moral of the story: you can always **look at compiler** output for inspiration on how to do something, and will often see tricks you didn't think of initially.